# Minecraft - recovered level.dat doesn't work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing Minecraft v1.7.5 on Vista (i know!).

Mine and my son's creative mode game disappeared from the menu - i think it might have been accidentally deleted.  The folder was still there in `<user>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves\Arlo's World`, but there was no `level.dat` or `level.dat_old` in it.

I used Recuva to search for deleted level.dat files and it found a `level.dat_old` file from that folder that could be recovered.  I recovered that, put it back in the folder, copied it and renamed the copy to `level.dat`, so that the `.minecraft\saves\Arlo's World` folder had a `level.dat` and a `level.dat_old` file again.

But, on starting the game, it still doesn't show up in the list of worlds in the single player game list.

Is there something else I need to do, to make the game add it to the list of options?  Comparing the world folder with a still-working world, it looks like everything else is still present.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new world and replacing that world's level.dat file? If it works, great, if not it lets you know the file is at least somewhat corrupted.

Comment: @getfugu Ah, good idea.... nope.  I guess it is corrupted.  Bummer.  It had our massive 70-block-high pyramid and all sorts of cool stuff in it.  Still don't know what happened.  I think either he deleted it by accident trying to do something else or his little sister was just mucking about on the computer and did it.

Comment: @getfugu oh there is still hope - just saw a link to this in another similar question. https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-tools/1261480-minecraft-region-fixer

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the player inventory or positions, you could create a new world (with a different name), close minecraft and then copy the region files from your old world to the new save folder. This would effectively insert the chunks from your old world into the new one, but can cause cliffs to appear at the edges of the "old world" (different terrain height) and you'd have to find out where the old chunks are located (fly around 0,0 in creative mode and look for the mentioned cliffs as a clue).

You can also try opening your old level.dat with an NBT editor and look for the world seed: creating a new world with your old seed prevents ugly cliffs from appearing. You could also find out the old player coordinates from the level.dat and simply teleport there in the merged world instead of having to search for it.

edit: I the NBT editor I used for similar things is called [NBT Explorer](https://github.com/jaquadro/NBTExplorer)

Comment: Thanks - it's creative so inventory isn't an issue, thanks.  I think i have some photos of it showing the coordinates.  I'll try this, thanks.